# Android set Custom ringtone for user defined number

Tags: android, android-studio

I am writing code for setting custom ringtone in android. Took help from other answers in stackoverflow. Here is the code.

```
private void setContactRingtone(String number) {
    final Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number));
// The columns used for `Contacts.getLookupUri`
    final String[] projection = new String[]{
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY
    };
// Build your Cursor
    final Cursor data = getContentResolver().query(lookupUri, projection, null, null, null);
    data.moveToFirst();
    try {
        // Get the contact lookup Uri
        final long contactId = data.getLong(0);
        final String lookupKey = data.getString(1);
        final Uri contactUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.getLookupUri(contactId, lookupKey);
        if (contactUri == null) {
            // Invalid arguments
            return;
        }

        File file = new File(this.getFilesDir() + File.separator + "ringtone.mp3");
        final String value = Uri.fromFile(file).toString();

        final ContentValues values = new ContentValues(1);
        values.put(ContactsContract.Contacts.CUSTOM_RINGTONE, value);
        getContentResolver().update(contactUri, values, null, null);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done!!!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        // Don't forget to close your Cursor
        data.close();
    }
 }
```

The code is not assigning the user defined ringtone to the contact. There are no exceptions generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO the problem was in android 10 asset folder is accessible through inputstream.[Referred this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50322985/1966655)

Here we create a temporary file and write to external storage. And then read that file.